# Microsoft Azure BizTalk Service

Tags: azure, biztalk

We are considering what to do with a BizTalk 2006 server that we need to replace (windows Server 2003 EOL coming up).

It has been suggested that we could use the BizTalk service within the Azure offering to replace it. However one of the processes that we have uses a POP3 connector as part of the Orchestration and I can't see this as one of the connectors offered in Azure.

Does anyone know if it is in there or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, Azure BizTalk Services is not always a viable upgrade path from BizTalk Server.  In cases where there is feature parity, it is essentially an entire new application for Azure BizTalk Services, though you can reuse some artifacts, such as Schemas and Maps.

Perhaps the recommendation was actually to migrate to a full BizTalk Server running on an Azure VM.  That would be typically simple upgrade* from BizTalk server 2006 to 2013.

*FYI, from BizTalk Server 2006, you will have to make an intermediate step to BizTalk Server 2006 R2, 2009 or 2010 before finally upgrading the project to 2013.

Comment: Hi the information is very useful - I don;t think we would necessarily upgrade as such and we are more likely to use a fresh install / clean server and rebuild the application we have on the server in the new format

Comment: Correct, you would never upgrade a BizTalk server, I'm talking specifically about the Visual Studio Solution.  There is no direct upgrade from the 2006 Project system to the 2013 Project system.